# How can to post JSON data to Printful using their API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

So I have a JS web app I'm working on that utilizes JSON data pretty heavily. It also tends to fit Printful's API capabilities, however--the web is lacking any sort of example of how to go about carrying out an API call to POST the JSON data I have which is really just an image URL with a specific product type.

So as I'm reading their website API documentation for producing an order, they provide request body examples, a try it demo, but they don't provide a real world example of in the form of source code.

What I'm trying to do is simply process an order by specifying a URL to an image, then applying the product variant to the order.

See: https://www.printful.com/docs/orders (see Create A New Order about 2 quarters down the page.)

So in my mind this is along the lines of how I would **START** to go about it (I know the code isn't workable but the logic of it is,) but my overall issue is I don't know how to format the API call to pass the call on a button click.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.example.com/files/tshirts/example.psd',
data: '{"name":"jonas"}', // or JSON.stringify ({name: 'jonas'}),
success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json'
```

});

Any sort of help would be appreciated. Usually Platform APIs have real world examples of how to utilize their API!

Comment: `$('button-selector').on('click', function() { <insert your code here> })`

Comment: The only issue is how would I carry out an API call using the api key to create a new order? A real world example isn’t specified on their site. There’s literally no examples on the web or in their documentation definitively.